# Ubuntu 13.04 Audio and Bluetooth issue

Tags: wireless, sound, 13.04, bluetooth

UPDATE:
Uninstalled the drivers and now everything is working fine. Wifi is connecting without any problem now. The audio and bluetooth problem still remains.

Sound settings still shows **"Dummy Output"** when system is turned on. I have to use `alsa force-reload` inorder for the audio to work. 
Bluetooth settings shows **No Adapter Found**

`lsusb` for bluetooth shows

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
```

---

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 and have been trying to get the system to connect to wireless driver. I've installed the drivers from **Software Updates -> Additional Drivers** but then, under the driver name, it says "This Device is using an alternate driver". I can enable wifi through the indicator in the panel but it doesn't detect any network.

I'm using Broadcom BCM4313 wireless adapter.

There are other problems that I am experiencing, like the "Bluetooth Adapter Not Found" error, and "Dummy Output" in the audio settings.

I have the latest update installed but the issues still remain.
The output of `lspci` is

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 12)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 12)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 06)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev 06)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 2 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 06)
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8152 v1.1 Fast Ethernet (rev c1)
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 02)
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 02)
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 02)
ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
```

and 
`lsmod | grep -e wl -e b43` gives

```
wl                   3074449  0 
lib80211               14352  2 wl,lib80211_crypt_tkip
cfg80211              510937  1 wl
```

The output of `rfkill list` is

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

The wireless issue is the most irritating one. It would be really nice if anyone could help me with the audio problem too. I have tried many solutions I found on askubuntu and ubuntuforums, as well as other websites, but nothing worked.

Thanks.

Comment: Provide `lsusb` for the bluetooth module. Is the audio working after the `force-reload`?

Comment: @grimpitch  Updated question with lsusb. And yes, audio works fine after force-reload

Answer (score 2):

you have first to deactivate the driver you installed from `jockey`, and then you can use `ndisgtk` 
if you have your wireless driver for windows this program will create a driver for linux starting from Windows driver

if it did not work you can see [this](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Devices) for detecting you wireless card then download the driver from [here](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Download)

or finally if those did not worked try this
`sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer` or this `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer` in the command line

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I tried uninstalling all the drivers and  wireless works fine now.